# What does coming soon mean on the LEGO store website?

Tags: lego-store

I'm hoping people who are more familiar with ordering from the LEGO website can help me with trying to pre-order some items.

LEGO has announced a range of Super Mario sets with a lot of fanfare - YouTube Videos, advertisements, etc. The full range of planned products can be seen on their website: [Lego Store Website (en-de)](https://www.lego.com/en-de/themes/super-mario)

However, with the exception of the [Starter Course](https://www.lego.com/en-de/product/adventures-with-mario-starter-course-71360) which is shown to be shipping on 1st August, the rest are announced as 'Coming Soon', and clicking through on individual items shows 'Coming Soon on 1 August 2020' ([for example here](https://www.lego.com/en-de/product/bowser-s-castle-boss-battle-expansion-set-71369)).

I'm not certain how to interpret that - does that mean that sets are scheduled to be released on 1st August, or that they will become available for pre-order on that date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Coming Soon on 1 August 2020" generally means the time when "Add to basket" button becomes available (usually at midnight) so you can actually buy the set. This means you cannot really pre-order it in advance, unless there is some sort of VIP promotion (this is announced in advance), which works for some releases and allow sets to be purchased a day, week or two in advance.

If set is in high demand on release day it can quickly can be marked as "on back-order". That is your order is accepted, but shipping is delayed.

Comment: "usually at midnight" might variate in different time zones, right?

Comment: @mindstormsboi I have never tried to shop for particular set in multiple time zones, so this isn't something I could advise on. My experience is based on shopping in Europe.

Comment: I can confirm it's midnight at least for CET. When I ordered the NES, the "Add to basket" button became available just a few minutes before 1 August 2020.